# Can the index name be accessed/retrieved from a pandas.core.groupby.generic.SeriesGroupBy object?

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I created a pandas.core.groupby.generic.SeriesGroupBy object from a DataFrame like so:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(16).reshape((4,4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
gobj = df['B'].groupby(df['A'])
```

I know how to retrieve the column name from `gobj` (`gobj._selection_name` returns 'B'), but I don't know how to retrieve the name of the index (which is 'A'). Is it possible to access/retrieve that from `gobj`?

Comment: Thank you! That returns a list of objects that can be accessed for the name. In this example it would be `gobj.grouper.groupings[0].name`. Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is

```
gobj.keys.name

Out[57]: 'A'
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [source code](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/groupby/generic.py#L1215-L1217) it looks like there are three options:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(16).reshape((4,4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
gobj = df.groupby(['C', 'A'])['B']

print(gobj.grouper.result_index.names)
print(gobj.grouper.names)
print(gobj.grouper.groupings)

# out
# ['C', 'A']
# ['C', 'A']
# [Grouping(C), Grouping(A)]
```